# What is the difference between <> All and Not In

Tags: t-sql

Could you please tell me the differences between

```
select CustomerId from Customer Where TerritoryId <> All(select TerritoryId from Salesperson)

select CustomerId from Customer where TerritoryId NOT IN (select TerritoryId from Salesperson)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference in result but there is a bit different semantics.

`X [comparison] ALL(set)` mean that `set` is empty or the comparison is `TRUE` for each entry in the set.

`X NOT IN (set)` means that X does not belong to the set.

While `[comparison]` is "not equal", both forms are equivalent. But for other comparisons it may be different.